# An inequality about a.s. convergence

Tags: convergence, probability-inequalities

Let $X_n ‎\rightarrow‎ X$  in almost surely convergence. Is this true?
$$|X_n-X|\leq 2|X_n|\quad \text{for Sufficiently large n}$$

Comment: Hint: if $|X|\gt 0$, then eventually $|X_n-X| \le |X|/2$. The triangle inequality does the rest.

Comment: but this change right side of inequality. $2|X_n|\neq |X|/2$

Comment: If you draw a picture, it should be obvious.

Comment: draw a picture?! sorry i cannot understand.

Comment: Then please explain what "$|\cdot|$" means.  Usually it is interpreted as a norm, which implies it defines a [distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space) between $X$ and $X_n$.  Distances mean you can do geometry.